# Split screen half and half with image occupying a part

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner, I would like to know how I divide the screen in half, where on the left is a form, and on the right is an image that occupies the entire height of the screen. In a simple way.

Below is a link to exactly how I wanted it to look:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiNbu.png)

Comment: Investigate CSS display flex or grid and object-fit or background-size cover along with vw and vh units. Have a go at coding this and if you are still stuck put your code and a description of the problem you are having with it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple layout with Flex Settings

```
<div class="Full_width">
    <div class="set">
    <form>
    <label>name
    <input type="text">
    </label>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="duble_Set">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg?hmac=i0yVXW1ORpyCZpQ-CknuyV-jbtU7_x9EBQVhvT5aRr0">
    </div>
    </div>

    <style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .Full_width {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 400px;
    }
    .Full_width .set, .Full_width .duble_Set {
        width: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .duble_Set img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    label {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    
    </style>
```